# How to call webservice continuously without outofmemoryerror?

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-volley

I have used volley for background task and i got out of memory exception. Here is my code

What i have done is Calling method every 10 sec by using handler like

```
        handlerGetJockyLatLong = new Handler();
            runnableJockyLatLong = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    handlerGetJockyLatLong.postDelayed(runnableJockyLatLong, 10000);
                    getJockyLatLongFromBackEnd();
                }
            };
       handlerGetJockyLatLong.postDelayed(runnableJockyLatLong, 10000);
```

Here is my method

```
private void getJockyLatLongFromBackEnd() {
    final String getJockyID_URL = getProfileInformationURL(getUserAccessToken(UserSideTrackingPage.this), Other_UserID);
    Log.e("getJockyID_URL", getJockyID_URL);

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, getJockyID_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if (response != null && !response.startsWith("<HTML>")) {
              }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Error", error.toString());
        }
    });

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    queue.add(request);
}
```

I am getting outofmemoryerror and get crash here

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
```

Please suggest me what i have to do. In this case i have to update the UI every time when response come.

Comment: check my answer.let me know if it is working or not

Comment: @DaminiMehra Ok. I am trying this and i will update u

Answer (score 0):

try this when you call the url:

```
 try {
            NetworkController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().get(getJockyID_URL);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Networkcontroller.class:

```
public class NetworkController extends Application {

private static final String TAG = NetworkController.class.getSimpleName();

private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

private static NetworkController mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
}

public static synchronized NetworkController getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: where i need to place this NetworkController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().get(getJockyID_URL); ? In my method?

Comment: @Rajasekherreddy put it below your url like final String getJockyID_URL = getProfileInformationURL(getUserAccessToken(UserSideTrackingPage.this), Other_UserID);
    Log.e("getJockyID_URL", getJockyID_URL); NetworkController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().get(getJockyID_URL);

Comment: @Rajasekherreddy yes

Comment: So do i need to remove this  RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        queue.add(request);

Comment: @Rajasekherreddy no need to remove

Comment: May i know what is the use of this extra line will do NetworkController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().get(getJockyID_URL);